# how to convert months into days when using relativedelta?

Tags: python, python-dateutil

Here is my method

```
def get_remaining_days_in_financial_month(self, from_day):
    current_financial_day = date(from_day.year, from_day.month,
                                 self.financial_day_of_month)
    end_financial_month = current_financial_day + relativedelta(months=+1)
    delta = relativedelta(end_financial_month, from_day)
    remaining_days_in_financial_month = delta.days
    return remaining_days_in_financial_month
```

When I debug, I see

```
current_financial_day = 2013-06-01
delta = relativedelta(months=+1)
end_financial_month = 2013-07-01
from_day = 2013-06-01
remaining_days_in_financial_month = 0
```

Although this information is correct, I would like to know the number of `days`, because number of days changes from `28` in Feb, to `30` in June and `31` in August

How can I achieve this? The [dateutil](http://labix.org/python-dateutil) library doesn't offer a way it seems

Thank you

Comment: The whole point of `relativedelta` is that `relativedelta(months=+1)` doesn't _have_ a fixed number of days, because it can added to any date. So, if that's not what you want, don't use it.

Comment: I have a use case, where a user I need to calculate next month for a user financial month and see the number of days left from some other day

Comment: And for that use case, you don't want `relativedelta`, because it will give you a delta of 1 month; you want an absolute delta in days.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `datetime.timedelta()`; simply subtract the two dates:

```
delta = end_financial_month - from_day
return delta.days
```

Answer (score 11):

It seems there's some confusion about what a `timedelta` is versus a `relativedelta`.

A `timedelta` is a **context-free** duration. Think of it as some number of microseconds.  When you take a `datetime` and add a `timedelta` to it, you get a `datetime` that number of microseconds in the future, which is defined agnostic to varying month lengths, leap years, etc.

A `relativedelta` is a **context-sensitive** duration. Add "a month" to February 1. Add "a month" to August 1. You'll be adding a different number of microseconds in each case, because "a month" (as a duration) has different meanings depending on the reference point or context. The same thing goes for adding "a year" when leap years are involved.

Adding two `timedelta` instances makes perfect sense and is well-defined. You're just adding two "number of microseconds."

Adding two `relativedelta` instances isn't so straightforward and, looking at the documentation, appears to be disallowed.

---

All that being said, Martijn's answer is of course correct. I just wanted to clarify the difference in meaning between these two concepts.